Does the canonical distribution assign probability to microstates or macrostates?
In the standard derivations I have seen they come up with the expression of canonical distribution as function of E; the energy of the system in contact with a reservoir. But this energy which we would insert into the distribution function is the energy of the macrostate right? I mean of the whole system? That's how the derivations begin. But how do we use this distribution to find the probability of the system to be in a specific microstate? For example to find the average occupancy of an energy level in a many particle ensemble obeying Fermi Dirac statistics, we use the canonical distribution function to find probability of specific microstates; how are we doing this?

It is actually both.
$$\tag1P^{\text{sys}+\text{rsv}}_\text{micro}=\frac1\Omega\qquad\implies\qquad P^\text{sys}_\text{micro}\propto\mathrm e^{-E_i/k_BT}\qquad\implies\qquad P^\text{sys}_\text{macro}\propto g_E\,\mathrm e^{-E/k_BT}$$
where $g_E$ is the microstate multiplicity of that system energy macrostate.
Note that the above is the chain of reasoning that derives the canonical distribution from the microcanonical distribution; the canonical distribution simply postulates the middle and/or the rightmost term and be done with it.

Shouldn't probability of occurrence of any microstate be equal?

That's the left-most statement. It is only true in microcanonical.

Could you please elaborate?

Anyway I have found my answer. Thank you for responding though.

You're confused about the definition of microstate and macrostate.  The energy of the microstate is the energy of the whole system.  What is meant by the term microstate is just that we're specifying the specific state of the system down to every last microscopic detail.  The macrostate, on the other hand, is just the state of the system as determined by a few parameters like temperature and pressure.  Thus, if we know the macrostate, then we only know the probability distribution of the microstates; at a given temperature, there is a certain probability that the system will be in a microstate with a given energy, and that probability is given by the canonical distribution. Being in thermal contact with a reservoir is what causes the energy of the system to fluctuate so that there is no one definite energy associated with a definite temperature.

Okay say I have 4 red balls among some 10 balls in a box. Then probability of picking a red ball isn't same as picking a specific red ball right? The term exp(-E/kT) is already proportional to the no of microstates with that E; then repeating E value for different microstates is only repeating that same number. Then what is the point?

The probability of being in energy E is proportional to exp(-E/kT) multiplied by the degeneracy of the energy E, which is the number of microstates with energy E.  The point of "repeating that same number" is that you get the exact probability when you use the exact number of microstates with energy E multiplied by exp(-E/kT) and then divided by the partition function, which is the sum over all microstates multiplied by their respective exp(-E/kT).

Microstate
Factor $e^{-E_i/(k_BT)}$ is the probability of a microstate $i$. The canonical distribution then gives probability of a microstate:
$$
p_i=Z^{-1}e^{-\frac{E_i}{k_BT}}, Z = \sum_ie^{-\frac{E_i}{k_BT}}.
$$
Degeneracy factor
There are $g(E)$ microstates corresponding to the same energy $E$:
$$
g(E)=\sum_i\delta_{E_i,E}.
$$
Thus, the probability of finding the system in a state of energy $E$ (i.e., any of these microstates) is
$$
p(E)=\sum_i\delta_{E_i,E}Z^{-1}e^{-\frac{E_i}{k_BT}}=Z^{-1}g(E)e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}}
$$
Macrostate
System energy is a canonical ensemble is not fixed, and does not determine a macrostate. Instead, macrostate is characterized by a temperature. Moreover, neither microcanonical, nor canonical ensemble assing a probability to macrostates - these are not probabilistic, but reflect the observed certain/deterministic state of the system.

I wrote what I found convincing. Sorry this is handwritten.






As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
